# Registering types in unity 2.0 using Reflection (Not generic)

Tags: c#, reflection, unity-container

I need to to dynamically register my types in unity based on namespace filtering.

Here is my code :

```
 var q = from t in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                  .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                    where (t.IsInterface || t.IsClass) && t.Namespace == namespaceToAdd
                    select t;

            var types = q.ToList();

            types.Where(t => t.IsInterface).Select(i=>               
                    {
                        var matchingClass = types.Where(c => c.IsClass && i.IsAssignableFrom(c)).FirstOrDefault();
                         if (matchingClass != null)
                        {
                            container.RegisterType(i, matchingClass, null, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())();
                        }

                    });
```

but the container call fails : "Method name" expected.
"i" is the reflected interface
"matchingClass" the corresponding implementation type.

I've read the topics about this in SO but did not find my solution (switching to Unity 3.0, which does this is not an option).

Msdn wasn't helpful either (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507499(v=pandp.30).aspx)

The code will be cleaned after (I'll use only one form of linq, once this works :) )

What did I miss ?

Comment: Have you tried breaking into your code right before the exception is thrown? Also, while doing an action in a .Select() works, it really is a good way to go around looking for trouble; use a for or foreach loop on every elements in "types.Where(t => t.IsInterface)" and move your code in there. It will improve clarity, and make it easier to debug.

Comment: I said that the linq code was not clean but was not the source of the pb. Moreover, the error issues at edit time so I cannot  debug into it :)

Comment: "but the container call fails" <-- So... you call the container at "edit time"?

Comment: No, the code stops to to be valid at this line :)

Comment: Add a `Console.WriteLine` right after `matchingClass = types.Where(...)` and output something like `string.Format("{0}: {1}", i.Name, matchingClass .Name)`. Do you see anything weird in there?

Comment: No, Results are as expected : interface: class Implementing interface.